# Change button color after success callback function is executed in Ionic/Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

First of all I am a programming noob, I am trying to build an ionic app for sending commands to arduino via bluetooth.

```
   <ion-content padding>

   <div padding>

      <div ion-button clear block medium>
          <a ion-button color="energetic" outline  full  (click)="tab=1" [outline]="tab==2"> Slider</a>
          <a ion-button color="danger" full   [outline]="tab==1" (click)="tab=2"> Position</a>
      </div>
  </div>
<div [hidden]="tab==2">
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header text-center>
      <h2>Turn Light ON/OFF</h2>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>

      <div text-center>
        <button ion-button icon-left color="primary" round (click)="toggle()" large>
                      <ion-icon name="ios-sunny-outline"></ion-icon>
                      ON/OFF
                      <ion-icon name="sunny"></ion-icon>
                    </button>

      </div>


      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label> OFF/ON </ion-label>
          <ion-toggle checked="false" (ionChange)="toggle()"></ion-toggle>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>



    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</div>
<div [hidden]="tab==1">
<div text-center>

    <button ion-button icon-left color="dark" round outline (click)="Enable()">
  <ion-icon name="bluetooth" color="danger"></ion-icon>
  Show Bluetooth List
</button>
  </div>

  <ion-card>
    <ion-list *ngFor="let list of lists">
     <button ion-item (click)="connect(list.address)">
      <ion-icon name="bluetooth" item-left></ion-icon>
      {{list.name}}
    </button> 
    </ion-list>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card>
  <ion-card-header text-center color="danger">
    Status
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content text-center>
    {{status}}
  </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>

</div>
 </ion-content>
```

This function iterate through the paired devices and whenever I click on particular button/device, connect() function is fired, and on connection a success call back function is excuted.

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',

})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }


public tog: any = 'OFF';
 public tab= 1;

  toggle() {
    switch (this.tog) {
      case 'ON':
        this.Write('OFF');
        this.tog = 'OFF';

        break;
      case 'OFF':
        this.Write('ON');
        this.tog = 'ON';

      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  status : any;
  lists : any ;
  Enable(){

    BluetoothSerial.isEnabled().then((data)=> {
      this.status = 'Bluetooth is ON';
      BluetoothSerial.list().then((allDevices) => {            
            this.lists = allDevices;
        });
        BluetoothSerial.discoverUnpaired().then((devices)=>{
          this.lists.push(devices);
          this.status= 'discovered some devices';
        }).catch((err)=> { this.status= 'No devices were found'; });
    }).catch((error)=>{ this.status='Bluetooth is not turned on'; });    
  }

  connect(mac){

    BluetoothSerial.connect(mac).subscribe((success)=>{

      this.status= 'Bluetooth connection is successful with'+ success;
    });
  }

 Write (msg){

   BluetoothSerial.write(msg).then( res =>{
    this.status = ' This has been written :' + res;
   }).catch(res=> function(){
     this.status = ' This has not been written :' + res;
   });


 }
}
```

Problem : .subscribe does not update this.status variable on view,unless I switch to other page and come back to it again.

Request : I would like to show user that connection to their selected device has been done by changing the color of selected button. In addition while It is connecting to bluetooth device, I would like show some sort of notification that it is connecting to device please wait? How I can implement this?

I would deeply appreciate any help !!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the waiting notification you need to implement the [loadingController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/loading/LoadingController/) (placed in your code within connect() function).

For the button color,

My suggestion: You should use your array `lists` to create another array `deviceListWithStatus:Array<any>` in that array push each object from the `lists` `{device:[a device object from the list],status:[the assoc status value]}`.

```
  status : any;
  lists : any ;
  deviceListWithStatus:Array<any>;
  Enable(){
    deviceListWithStatus = [];

   BluetoothSerial.isEnabled().then((data)=> {
      this.status = 'Bluetooth is ON';
      BluetoothSerial.list().then((allDevices) => {            
            for(let i in allDevice){
       deviceListWithStatus.push({device:allDevice[i],status:'disconnected'})
            }
        });
        BluetoothSerial.discoverUnpaired().then((devices)=>{
            for(let i in devices){      deviceListWithStatus.push({device:devices[i],status:'disconnected'})
            }
          this.status= 'discovered some devices';
        }).catch((err)=> { this.status= 'No devices were found'; });
    }).catch((error)=>{ this.status='Bluetooth is not turned on'; });    
  }
```

Then in your html template:

```
    <ion-list *ngFor="let dev of deviceListWithStatus">
     <button ion-item [ngStyle]="(dev.status=='connected')?{'background-color':  'green'}:{'background-color':  'red'}" (click)="connect(dev)">
      <ion-icon name="bluetooth" item-left></ion-icon>
      {{dev.device.name}}
    </button> 
    </ion-list>
```

Then change your `connect` function such as this:

```
  connect(dev){
      let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'Please wait...'
      });

      loading.present();

    BluetoothSerial.connect(dev.device.address).subscribe((success)=>{
      loading.dismiss();
      dev.status = 'connected';
      this.status= 'Bluetooth connection is successful with'+ success.;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate ! However I did not understand how conditional varibable status will work? [ngStyle] will be applied to each and every object in device ( could be 0 and could be 100 devices), I only wants to change the color of selected device and only after the .susbcribe callback...?? Thanks

Comment: I don t get it. Is the button a single element on a html page template or is it a component (with it s own component *.ts file and component html template file) that you use several time in your html page template, or do you use several time button on the same page by copy/pasting the same html code on the page html template? Maybe you need to post more input about your code and its organization.

Comment: it is component that its own .ts and .component.html file.  also when looping through list items, each item generates a button item in <ion-list. Hope this is clear? and whenever I click on any button I pass list.address parameter to connect function. I was wondering if can do ngif inside status== function??

Comment: so you have an `ngFor` and each iteration in the array (on which this `ngFor` applies) creates its own `CustomButton` (let s call it like that to avoid confusion with regular button) which is a self standing component with it own `selector` (named likely custom-button in that case) . If it is so, why can t you pass some properties to your `CustomButton` with `@Input`, and among those `@Input` properties, its `status`. So when you change the `status`  on one of the object of the array, it should update as well its respective `CustomButton` appearance.

Comment: I dont think it has its own selector... You solution is way too advance for me mate.. Im not from IT background.. I apologise for not understanding your solution.

Comment: No problem. I think you need to post more of your code and its organization if you want people to have a better understanding of your issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130804/discussion-between-amrit-sohal-and-nyluje).

Comment: Looks wonderful, I will give it  try as soon as I get home. Thanks man, I really appreciate  you efforts.. Star 

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly... Thanks geez.... I appreciate your help.